# How do I get an out-of-office period to appear in the calendar (Lotus Notes 7)?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have created an out-of-office period from the calendar view (Tools->Out-of-Office) and have checked it is enabled. But no trace appears in the calendar. Does anyone know how to get it to show up?

Comment: Is it *expected* to appear in the calendar?

Comment: @slhck, _I_ was expecting it to appear in the calendar, but I'm no authority on the matter...

Comment: I just checked in our office and it seems they always manually enter out-of-office pseudo-appointments. (Yes, that's totally lame, but it's Lotus Notes, so you're probably used to lame workarounds.)

Comment: Depending on the version of Notes, and if you are using the agent style vs the router style of OOO, it usually will prompt to mark you as busy or not when you enable it. If your system isn't setup to mark you as busy, you'll have to use the all day event option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

out of office periods don't show up in the calendar you'd need to book a multi day appointment, at least it didn't in the three years we used it at the company where I work.

Comment: It can be configured to mark you as busy, but Notes can be customized significantly more than other systems, so it really depends on what the administrators have enabled and what's available with the mailfile design.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to work in the opposite order.  Whenever I am taking a vacation day, I add that as a new calendar enty and simply select the catagory "Vacation".   When you Save, a popup appears automatically asking if you wish to setup the Out of Office Agent.  Click Yes and the agent opens for you to fine tune.